# MySQL Copy a .sql file into a database from a ssh connection

Tags: mysql, database, ssh, scp

I want to copy a database from one server to another (Germany and China), since they are both hosted servers by two different service providers I can't just replicate them because they won't allow me to change the configfiles of the servers. I came to the conclusion that I need to setup a 3rd Server at my location from which I then can copy the data towards the other server so I have a "Master" in Germany a "Slave" in China and a "Messenger" at my location. All the Commands must be executed on the "messenger" by a bash script. The script works fine until the file should be sent into the database there it gives me the error that the file doesn't exist, but it exists.

```
mysqldump -h [host] -u [user] -p[mysqlpassword] databasename > filename.sql
```

```
sshpass -p [mypassword] ssh [ChineseServerIp] -l [user] sshpass -p [mypassword] scp user@GermanServerIP:filename.sql /home
```

```
sshpass -p [mypassword] ssh [ChineseServerIP] -l [user] mysql -u [mysqlUser] -p[mysqlpassword] Databese < /home/filename.sql
```

I can't just copy the file from the "messenger" Server into the Chinese one, it just would take to long  because of the "great Chinese firewall" (I gzip the .sql file and then Transfer it when its on the Chinese one I unzip and upload it).

Comment: Is this a one-time-shot or shall  it be executed on a regular basis via script?

Comment: it should be executed on regular basis via the script.

Comment: Have you tried executing these commands directly in the terminal, not via the script?

Comment: yes, I did that but there it also gives me the same eror that the dictonary doesn´t exists.

Answer (score 0):

its solved, I just had to set the inserting of the sql file in ""

```
sshpass -p [mypassword] ssh [ChineseServerIP] -l [user] "mysql -u [mysqlUser] -p[mysqlpassword] Databese < /home/filename.sql"
```